# OrientDB graph database design: storing properties on edge vs nodes

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases

I am using OrientDB to store information about video rentals. I represent members and movies as nodes. And whenever a member borrows a movie I add an edge between them. The dataset has user borrowing movie multiple times. Also I am required to store in which month/season (still deciding which will suit our needs but besides the point) was the movie rented. I was planning to store the above mentioned detail on the edge.But I came across this: 
http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Performance-Tuning-Graph.html

And it is recommended to avoid storing properties on edges. I wanted to know whether I should change my approach ? If yes then what is the alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case you might opt for the creation of property directly on the edge. The alternative to store data related to rental is to create a third node (ex. RentalData) between Member and Movies and utilize PK and FK fields, but it would be similar to the relational DB and not necessary.

I reproduced a small DB:

```
create class Member extends V;
create property Member.id integer;
create property Member.name string;
create property Member.surname string;
create index Member.id unique;


create class Movie extends V;
create property Movie.id integer;
create property Movie.title string;
create property Movie.minutes integer;
create index Movie.id unique;

create class borrows extends E;
create property borrows.rentaldate Datetime;

create vertex Member set id = 1, name = "Paul", surname = "Green";
create vertex Member set id = 2, name = "John", surname = "Smith";
create vertex Member set id = 3, name = "Frank", surname = "Redding";

create vertex Movie set id = 1, title = "Interstellar", minutes = 170;
create vertex Movie set id = 2, title = "The Gladiator", minutes = 176;

create edge borrows from (select from Member where id = 1) to (select from Movie where id = 1) set rentaldate = sysdate();
create edge borrows from (select from Member where id = 1) to (select from Movie where id = 2) set rentaldate = sysdate();
create edge borrows from (select from Member where id = 2) to (select from Movie where id = 2) set rentaldate = sysdate();
create edge borrows from (select from Member where id = 3) to (select from Movie where id = 1) set rentaldate = sysdate();
create edge borrows from (select from Member where id = 3) to (select from Movie where id = 2) set rentaldate = sysdate();
```

I stored the "rentaldata" property directly on the edge "borrows" to associate the member to the movie borrowed and I think you could do it like me.

Answer (score 0):

From the very same link you provided:

> Use the schema
>
> Starting from OrientDB 2.0, if fields are declared in the schema,
>   field names are not stored in document/vertex/edge themselves. This
>   improves performance and saves a lot of space on disk.

[source](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Performance-Tuning.html#use-the-schema)